# Can I translate Trello into other languages, specifically French?

Tags: trello, translation, localization

Is there a way to translate Trello in other languages? I'm looking for French translation in particular.

Or is it possible to do this translation myself?

Comment: +1 – we would need it in German to be acceptable for our *whole* team.

Comment: Same here, in Swedish

Comment: Trello is now [available in French](https://twitter.com/trello/status/643761878649434113) but also Brazilian Portuguese, Spanish and German.

Comment: [More about Trello in French](http://blog.trello.com/voila-trello-is-taking-a-tour-de-france/).

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this currently. Other languages will come with future versions.

Comment: Thank you. If you need some help for the french translation, i can help :)

Comment: Any news on this feature?

Comment: Trello is now [available in French](https://twitter.com/trello/status/643761878649434113) but also Brazilian Portuguese, Spanish and German.