# Is there a way to change language in Trello?

Tags: trello, localization

Because seriously, looking at updates like "User added Enheter for nytenkning" or something (random typeish to illustrate) looks ridiculously stupid. I tried looking at the options, but there was nothing hinting to a way to do so.

Comment: related http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19825/5709

Comment: If you need Brazilian Portuguese, Spanish, German or French [this is now possible](https://trello.com/c/XFlKVtFe).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Currently, Trello is only available in English, Spanish, German, French and Portuguese.

Comment: This is [not true anymore](https://trello.com/c/XFlKVtFe). Brazilian Portuguese, Spanish, German and French are available and more to come.