# Trello translation

Tags: trello, localization, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I translate Trello into other languages, specifically French?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19825/can-i-translate-trello-into-other-languages-specifically-french)

Is there any way to keep me informed about your translation plans?

Quite a few people in my project speak English but I find your app the best and simplest to manage. It therefore is a hassle for them to deal with the application. At the same time I'd like to offer myself to translate the application to Spanish (Castilian).

Comment: [Trello is now available](https://trello.com/c/XFlKVtFe) in Brazilian, Portuguese, Spanish, German or French.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to contact Trello development team [by email](https://trello.com/help) asking for this feature, noting how others have asked for it before ([here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19825/can-i-translate-trello-into-other-languages-specifically-french)) and hope they'll include it on their [Development board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c). When they do, you'll be able to track its progress there (going from the list of ideas to "next up", "in progress" and all the way to "live").